# SQLAlchemy inner join NoneType is not iterable to avoid count()

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I need to check if student has pass this exam with exam id ( table marks has foreign keys to students and table exams)

```
student, exam = session.query(StudentModel,MarkModel)
                       .join(MarkModel)
                       .filter(and_(StudentModel.uuid == uuid, MarkModel.exam_id == exam_id))
                       .first()
```

but when is not in database I get error `NoneType is not iterable`

How to check without fetching exception ?
I wanted to avoid to execute two or more queries ( like to check first with count)

Comment: At a guess, the result of all of that is `None`, hence can't be unpacked to two names. Splitting it to multiple lines might help narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.first()` returns one query result, *or `None`*. There were no matches, `first()` returned `None` and unpacking `None` fails.

You can check for `None` explicitly by first storing the result:

```
result = session.query(StudentModel,MarkModel).join(MarkModel).filter(
    and_(StudentModel.uuid == uuid, MarkModel.exam_id == exam_id)).first()
if result is not None:
    student, exam = result
```

Or just catch the exception:

```
try:
    student, exam = session.query(StudentModel,MarkModel).join(MarkModel).filter(
        and_(StudentModel.uuid == uuid, MarkModel.exam_id == exam_id)).first()
except TypeError:
    # None returned, unpacking failed
    student = exam = None
```

Comment: rather than catch `TypeError`, you may want to use `.one()` instead of `.first()`, which will throw a more specific `NoResultsFound`

Comment: @Eevee: but if the OP wanted to allow for multiple results and only use the first, then `.one()` would be the wrong method to use.

Comment: true, but i'm hoping "uuid" and "exam_id" suggest that the row ought to be unique  :)